# Click event for a particular word from a sentence

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

Can we give click event for a particular word from a sentence. For example, let my label be 
'myLabel.text = @"contact 123@gmail.com";'. I want to give click event for 123@gmail.com. Is it possible in IOS5/IOS6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS5/6 there's a link detection system that will pick out links from a string, however it's not available in `UILabel`. If you can get away with using a `UITextView` then it'll work perfectly, if you desperately, definitely need a `UILabel` you'll need to work around it slightly and use something like [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or follow a similar approach and build your own `UILabel` replacement.